# setOnEditorActionListener not called

Tags: android, android-xml

I've updated my app and now the listener doesn't work.
I use this activity with to similar actions:
1. EditText (IP-Adress) & AutoCompleteTextView (subnetmask)
2. EditText (IP-Adress) & AutoCompleteTextView (host count; *without spinner*)

This class extends `NavigationDrawerActivity` which I use with `Intent`s to switch between this *two*  and other ones.

The button works fine.

**on Create of my main Activity**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //License and Google Analytics code removed

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    context=this;

    calc_screenSize(); //for the padding in initialise_views

    initialise_views(); //with findViewById
    initialise_table(); //subnettable with 4 quads, among other code

    this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

    btn_berechnen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            standard_go(false, true);

            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(et_input_IP.getWindowToken(), 0);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(et_input_SNM.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    });

    et_input_SNM.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {//not called - why?
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            Log.d("actionId",actionId+"");
            Log.d("actionId",EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE+"");

            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                standard_go(false, true);

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }); 

    //license check code rmoved
}
```

**activity_main.xml** and other *activity_xxx.xml* conains:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_ipAdresse"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Button_berechnen"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:hint="@string/input_ipAdresse"
        android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_small"
        android:textSize="@dimen/fontsize_medium" >

        <requestFocus android:layout_width="match_parent" />
    </EditText>

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/input_snm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/input_ipAdresse"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:imeActionLabel="@string/Button_berechnen"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone|flagNoExtractUi"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_small"
        android:textSize="@dimen/fontsize_medium" />
```

Comment: What do you mean it's "not called?" Do you mean the callbacks are never fired? Do you mean the line to actually set it is never called? Have to you tried debugging it with breakpoints? -- We need a little more info, and you should also post your LogCat so we can see if there are any errors

Comment: the callback are never fired; catlog is empty (no errors)

Comment: I've actually come across similar issues on some devices, and ended up using a TextWatcher instead, as it seemed pretty consistent. Have you tried this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html

Comment: this isn't called too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DONE with this:

```
et_input_SNM.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        Log.d("actionId","OnKeyListener: "+keyCode+" - "+KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER);
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
            standard_go(false, true);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: "This is only useful for hardware keyboards; a software input method has no obligation to trigger this listener.."http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html